# How to parse XML using Jackson API?

Tags: java, xml, rest, xml-parsing, jackson

I am using Jackson api to parse xml object.

```
<BESAPI xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BESAPI.xsd">
    <Employee Resource="https://abc:52311/api/employee/100"/>
    <Employee Resource="https://abc:52311/api/employee/200"/>
    <Employee Resource="https://abc:52311/api/employee/300"/>
    <Employee Resource="https://abc:52311/api/employee/400"/>
</BESAPI>
```

this is the structure of xml records. I want to get list of all resources as String. How can I achieve it using Jackson api?

Comment: By the way: Your XML example is invalid because it uses the `xsi:` prefix without defining it. You need to add `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` to the `BESAPI` root element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to write some Java classes modeling your XML content.
The classes get [`@JacksonXml...`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/package-summary.html)
annotations to tell Jackson the mapping between XML and Java.
These annotations are especially important when a Java name is different from the XML name.

One class is for representing the `<BESAPI>` root element:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "BESAPI")
public class BESAPI {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", namespace = XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI)
    private String noNamespaceSchemaLocation;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = false, localName = "Employee")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<Employee> employees;

    // public getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

and another class for representing the `<Employee>` element

```
public class Employee {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute=true, localName="Resource")
    private String resource;

    // public getters and setters (omitted here for brevity)
}
```

Then you can use Jackson's [`XmlMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper.html) for reading XML content.

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
File file = new File("example.xml");
BESAPI besApi = xmlMapper.readValue(file, BESAPI.class);
for (Employee employee : besApi.getEmployees()) {
    System.out.println(employee.getResource());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXml can do this:

```
final String data = ...
final SimpleXml simple = new SimpleXml();
final Element element = simple.fromXml(data);
for (final Element employee : element.children) {
    System.out.println(employee.attributes.get("Resource"));
}
```

Will output:

```
https://abc:52311/api/employee/100
https://abc:52311/api/employee/200
https://abc:52311/api/employee/300
https://abc:52311/api/employee/400
```

From maven central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.codemonstur</groupId>
    <artifactId>simplexml</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```